# Django ORM adds _id into JSON for ForeignKeys

Tags: json, django

> Behind the scenes, Django appends "_id" to the field name to create
>   its database column name.

Django ORM adds _id into ForeignKeys, so when I create json format, the column appears with _id at the end, how to remove _id ?

```
{
  "ModelID_id": 1,
  "ID": 1,
  "DataDefinitionID_id": 1
},

// JSON Builder
ModelDependecy_queryset = Modeldatadependency.objects.values().all() 
return Response({"ModelDataDependency": list(ModelDependecy_queryset)},200)

// Model file
class Modeldatadependency(models.Model):
    ID = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    ModelID = models.ForeignKey(Model, models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='ModelID', blank=True, null=True)
    DataDefinitionID = models.ForeignKey(Datadefinition, models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='DataDefinitionID', blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'ModelDataDependency'
        app_label = 'default'
```

Comment: You should show what you are doing to create this JSON.

Comment: I have added into question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a method that will return what you need

```
class Modeldatadependency(models.Model):
    ModelID = models.ForeignKey(Model, blank=True, null=True)
    DataDefinitionID = models.ForeignKey(Datadefinition, blank=True, null=True)`enter code here`

    def get_json(self):
        return dict(
            ModelID =self.ModelID,
            ID =self.id, 
            DataDefinitionID =self.DataDefinitionID)
```

Comment: Thank you, but how I can call this method in my code ? 

ModelDependecy_queryset = Modeldatadependency.objects.values().all() 
return Response({"ModelDataDependency": list(ModelDependecy_queryset)},200)

Comment: like any other model method.
ModelDependecy_queryset = Modeldatadependency.objects.all()
return Response({"ModelDataDependency.get_json(): list(ModelDependecy_queryset)},200)